# Error 'GoogleDataTransport/GDTClock.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

The problem is where I add "pod 'Firebase'" to Podfile and try run my app. I added GoogleService-Info.plist and try to add my app to firebase. How to fix it?

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    In file included from
/AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCCTUploader.m:17:
    //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/Private/GDTCCTUploader.h:19:9: fatal error: 'GoogleDataTransport/GDTUploader.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GDTUploader.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.m:17:
    //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/Private/GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.h:19:9: fatal error: 'GoogleDataTransport/GDTStoredEvent.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GDTStoredEvent.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    In file included from //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/GDTCCTPrioritizer.m:17:
    //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/GDTCCTLibrary/Private/GDTCCTPrioritizer.h:19:9: fatal error: 'GoogleDataTransport/GDTClock.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GDTClock.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    //AndroidStudioProjects/wts101/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:20:9: fatal error: 'GoogleDataTransport/GDTConsoleLogger.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleDataTransport/GDTConsoleLogger.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    ld: framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are are you sure you are in .xcworkspace file?
This is looks like a caused by having the .xcodeproj file open instead of .xcworkspace and so needed pods could not be founded.

Comment: How to change this? I use android studio. And I men on macOS

Comment: Try to find a .xcworkspace file in your project folder and run it. It should help (because pods generate new project scheme)

Comment: Running in Xcode with workspace is no problem. But how to run in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Try using pod update. The pod file may have been updated and you are just running an older version.

Answer (score 0):

the problem can be in the pod file,
work for me to replace:

`flutter_install_ios_engine_pod(File.realpath(_FILE_))`

with:

`flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(_FILE_))`

you can also delete the podfile and run "flutter create ." (flutter will regenerate for you the new podfile)

Answer (score -2):

I am using android studio

1. I cd to the directory ios then
2. Run "flutter clean"
3. Run "pod install"
4. Run "cd .."
5. Run "flutter run"
   And it worked for me.